# Telegram Bot gradle.build configuration

Tags: java, gradle, telegram-bot

I built a Telegram Bot with Maven and had following plugins:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>bot.BotApplication</mainClass>
                            <name>workerBot</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Now start new project with Gradle and want to include these plugins, but don't know how to do it. I'm pretty new with Gradle.

And I had Procfile file with this content:
`worker: sh target/bin/workerBot`

Can u help me translate this part of pom.xml to build.gradle? And will the Procfile be the same as with pom.xml?

Comment: Do you want to build an executable jar file ?

Comment: Really don't, because heroku will build it itself.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself is not reusable. Based on the actual output one option is
using Gradle 'distribution' to package it like the previous output - you will need to store the copies of scripts and replicate the structure in distribution { }

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html#header